# lambda expression with 2 parameters and mulitple result outputs

Tags: c#, methods, lambda, extension-methods

I am trying to find out if it is possible having two input parameters in a lambda expression function to have multiple results that can be put into an array, instead of using a for loop like below.

```
int N = 10;
int[] numbs = new int[N] { 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 15, 17, 28, 55 };
int[] results = new int[N-1];

for (int i=0; i < N-1; i++)
     results[i] = numbs[i+1] - numbs[i];

foreach (int i in results)
     Console.WriteLine(i);
```

> > output 2,1,1,1,3,4,2,11,17

Something like this:

```
results = numbs.Select( (x,y) => y-x );
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) to line up the array with itself, shifted by one index:

```
results = numbs.Zip(numbs.Skip(1), (n1, n2) => n2 - n1)
               .ToArray();
```

Comment: I had never heard of ZIP before, as I am still teaching myself how to use Lambda expressions.
@D Stanley Is there anyway you would create some type of tag for the ZIP method? Like ZIP-method or method-ZIP

Answer (score 0):

You can create you own extension methods (not sure what you mean by "tag"). You can also create your own iterators. The two can work well together. Here is an iterator extension method for applying a windowing function to one sequence.

```
public static class SlidingWindowExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Sliding<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Int32 windowSize, Func<IEnumerable<T>, T> function)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));            
        if (windowSize <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(windowSize), "Must be a positive integer");
        if (function== null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(function));         

        var window = new Queue<T>(source.Take(windowSize - 1));
        foreach (var element in source.Skip(windowSize - 1))
        {
            window.Enqueue(element);
            var result = function(window);
            window.Dequeue();
            yield return result;
        }
        //Note: does not yield any result if window size is more than the length of the sequence. 
        //      (At least, that way function is guaranteed to get windowSize elements.)
    }
}
```

Yours would be a special case of a window size of 2 and a difference function.

```
numb.Sliding(2, w => w.Skip(1).First() - w.First())
```

The function is a bit awkward. This is less so but has a more clunky setup.

```
Func<IEnumerable<int>, int> first = w => w.First();
Func<IEnumerable<int>, int> second = w => w.Skip(1).First();

numbs.Sliding(2, w => second(w) - first(w))
```

A step further

```
Func<IEnumerable<int>, int> diff = w => second(w) - first(w);   
numbs.Sliding(2, diff)
```

A bit fancier

```
Func<IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<int>> slidingDifference = source => source.Sliding(2, diff);
slidingDifference(numbs)
```

Another example: sliding average

```
numbs.Sliding(2, w => (w.Sum() / 2))
```

But, do check out [LINQ's Standard Query Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb394939.aspx).

[Code](http://share.linqpad.net/qguoc8.linq) for your [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) (highly recommended).

Comment: The "tag" request was for a stack overflow tag as there is none for ZIP in reference to lambda methods. As to your solution alli can say is really? Why would I be looking to expand my line of code tenfold? I was looking for a one line lambda solution. Thanks but no thanks.

Comment: Agreed in your case. Windowing is useful, though.